# Зачем придумали контексты исполнения, области видимости?

Tags: javascript

Мне не понятно про контекст (executoin context) и про области видимости (scopes).

**Зачем эту модель с контекстами и областями видимости вообще придумали???**

Везде нахожу только *описание* этой модели, а *причина*, по которой это все *так* придумали - нигде не написана. Ведь перед тем, как что-то сделать, должна быть весомая причина, чтобы что-то реализовать. Просто так же ничего не делается, так как программисты - люди логичные.

Comment: Ну а вы хотели чтобы все в одной куче было?

Comment: В книге "Кодеры за работой" (Coders at work) Питера Сайбела есть интервью с Бренданом Айком (автором первой персии JavaScript). Там он описывает как возник язык, что повляло на него и причины некоторых его решений.

Comment: Представте себе файл в 30к линий кода где все переменные видны для всех функций и объектов... А чтобы этого месива небыло используется логическое разделение функционала программы на контексты и области видимости

Comment: А тут принятие ответа не планируется?

Answer (score 6):

Для удобства. Чтобы не скидывать все в одну 'помойку'. Зачем вам везде видеть переменную если она используется только в одном блоке? 
Вот еще есть вариант демонстрирующий для чего это надо:

```
//так могут быть объявлены глобальные переменные:
var x;              //явное объявление без инициализации
a = 123;            //неявное объявление с инициализацией
var q = 'hello';    //явное объявление с инициализацией


//-----------------------------------
function test()
{
  var a = 555;         //  это локальная переменная, не имеющая
                       //  никакого отношения к объявленной выше
                       //  глобальной a,
                       //  поскольку она объявлена в теле функции
                       //  с помощью инструкции var

  q = q + ' world';    //изменилось значение глобальной
                       //  переменной q

alert('внутри функции a = ' + a);  
    //выведет окно с сообщением: 'внутри функции a = 555'
};


//-----------------------------------

//проверим значения глобальных переменных до и после вызова функции:


alert('до вызова функции a = ' + a);  
  //выведет окно с сообщением: 'до вызова функции a = 123'


test();    //вызов функции


alert('после вызова функции a = ' + a);  
  //выведет окно с сообщением: 'после вызова функции a = 123'


alert(' после вызова функции q = ' + q);  
  //выведет окно с сообщением: 
  //'после вызова функции q = Hello world'
```

Comment: @Dimon вместо (или в дополнение к) "спасибо" стоит отметить ответ как верный - галочка слева от вопроса, под стрелками.

Answer (score 4):

> Мне не понятно про контекст (executoin context) и про области видимости (scopes).

1. Области видимости есть (почти?) во всех языках. Потому что это удобно. Не должен я при написании функции думать, кто ещё использовал переменные с такими же именами, и не испорчу ли я ему что-нибудь, если моя функция вызвана из его.
   Объявил переменную и точно знаю - она лично моя.
2. Замыкания. Тоже очень удобно. Ты же не просто так помещаешь функцию внутрь? Если тебе не нужно ничего из окружающей функции, ты мог бы положить и рядом. А раз нужно, то почему бы не предоставить такую возможность?
   Все современные языки вводят лямбда-функции и замыкания. Некоторые лучше (C# обеспечивает полноценную работу с переменными), некоторые хуже (Java делает все переменные, попавшие в замыкание, readonly), некоторые в своём традиционном стиле (в Си++ программист сам думает, что ему надо, и что там со временем жизни).
   В джаваскрипте замыкание устроено очень удобно - можно читать, можно писать, всё хорошо со скоупами, всё живёт сколько нужно, сборщики мусора уже оптимизировали (хотя в некоторых условиях утечки памяти всё же могут происходить).
3. Область видимости - это функция, а не блок. Вероятно это связано с производительностью. В ранних версиях интерпретаторов была зависимость между вложенностью по замыканиям и временем, необходимым на обращение.
   Сейчас уже нет, и ES6 вводит `let`, `const` и блочную область на function declaration.
4. Контекст. Классика ООП-языков - `this` неявно передаётся первым параметром. А `this` там - это то, что до точки. Логично, удобно. Ну и в js пошли таким путём. А специфика языка уж привела к тому, что получилось - таскаем чужие методы, применяем к другим объектам, ну или просто теряем привязку.
   Опять же, ES5 вводит `bind`, а в ES Next Proposal есть синтаксис с двойным двоеточием вместо точки.